# Encriptar y Desencriptar un texto

Tags: java, encriptación, ejb

Necesito ingresar una palabra y que me la encripte de acuerdo a un Arreglo de letras.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primera linea es el Abecedario normal.
Segunda Linea es el remplazo para la encriptacion ej: A por G.

**Codigo JSP**

```
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <form  action="calcularservlet" method="POST">

        # de Horas<input type="text" name="t1">
        <input type="submit" value="Calcular">
        <br>

        lETRA<input type="text" name="t2">
        <input type="submit" value="encriptar">

        <br>
        lETRA<input type="text" name="t3">
        <input type="submit" value="Desencriptar">           

    </form>
```

**Codigo SERVLET:**

```
  out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet calcularservlet</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        int x= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("t1"));
        out.println("<h1>Salario es = " + calcularbean.calcular(x)+ "</h1>");

        String b = request.getParameter("t2");

        out.println("<h1>Texto encriptado = " + calcularbean.encrip(b)+ "</h1>");

        String c=request.getParameter("t3");
        out.println("<h1>Texto desencriptado = " + calcularbean.desencrip(c)+ "</h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
```

**CODIGO CALCULARBEAN(Metodos)**

```
public class calcularbean implements calcularbeanLocal {

String alfa = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
String deso = "GNTAHÑUBIOVCJPWDKQXELRYFMSZ ";

@Override
public String encrip(String b) {       

   for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++){
       b=b.replace(alfa.charAt(i),deso.charAt(i));  

   } 

    return b;

}

@Override
public String desencrip(String c) {

   for(int i=0;i<c.length();i++){
      c=c.replace(deso.charAt(i),alfa.charAt(i));
   }
   return c;
}
```

Al ejecutar no me muestra el texto encriptado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías usar un `array` de `char` para hacer los reemplazos, así no tendrías que crear tantos Strings en el proceso:

```
static String source="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
static String target="GNTAHÑUBIOVCJPWDKQXELRYFMSZ ";

public static String obfuscate(String s) {
    char[] result = new char[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int index = source.indexOf(c);
        result[i] = target.charAt(index);
    }

    return new String(result);
}

public static String unobfuscate(String s) {
    char[] result = new char[s.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        int index = target.indexOf(c);
        result[i] = source.charAt(index);
    }

    return new String(result);
}
```

He llamado a los métodos ofuscar y desofuscar porque realmente esto no es cifrar (no hay contraseña y para cualquier experto sería fácil deshacer la ofuscación)

Comment: Te doy la razón en que ya en estos tiempos no es seguro, pero en realidad si tiene clave (no se debe llamar contraseña, es otro concepto), la clave es la distancia que hay entre cada par del texto plano y el texto cifrado. Por ejemplo entre  A y G, la distancia es "6", entre B y N es 12... etc.
Referencia: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_de_Vigenère

Comment: Aquí la distancia no es fija, la A pasa a ser la G y la B la N. Realmente es como un [One-Time-Pad](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libreta_de_un_solo_uso) pero sin ser de un único uso.

Comment: Exacto como un one-time pad, que también tiene clave) O también como el cifrado de Vigenère (donde la distancia también es variable) pero con la condición que la clave sea del tamaño del texto original... convirtiéndose así en un one-time pad))

Comment: Perfecto me funciono estaba cometiendo un error al ingresar datos en minuscula, lo solucione con el to.UpperCase(); Gracias pro la ayuda amigo.